# Deep compare two JSON objects in testcafe

Tags: javascript, json, automation, compare, testcafe

How do I deep compare 2 JSON objects(having similar keys) in testcafe? Also, is there a way I can store the differences?

I need something like this -

```
test.requestHooks([requestMock])('deep compare JSON objects', async t => {
  const obj1 = hookedResponses['getJSON1'];
  const obj2 = hookedResponses['getJSON2'];
  const result = await t.compare(obj1, obj2);
});
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Possible (not familiar with testcafe) dupe: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: Are you actually talking about JavaScript objects?